# Add new observations around dates and duplicate values

Tags: r, lubridate

I have multiple observations associated with dates and want to add new observations for +-3 days around each existing date and copy the values for those days.

Example df:

```
library(lubridate)

Time <- c(as_date(17498), as_date(18498), as_date(18298))
Measurement <- c(11, 42, 28)
df <- data.frame(Time, Measurement)
```

Aimed df:

```
Time_edt <- c(as_date(17495),as_date(17496),as_date(17497),as_date(17498),as_date(17499),as_date(17500),as_date(17501), 
          as_date(18495),as_date(18496),as_date(18497),as_date(18498),as_date(18499),as_date(18500),as_date(18501), 
          as_date(18295),as_date(18296),as_date(18297),as_date(18298),as_date(18299),as_date(18300),as_date(1830))
Measurement_edt <- c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
                 42,42,42,42,42,42,42,
                 28,28,28,28,28,28,28)
df_edt <- data.frame(Time_edt, Measurement_edt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse` (especially `purrr`) you can do this...

```
map_df(seq_len(nrow(df)),         #run through the rows. map_df outputs a dataframe
       ~tibble(Time = seq(df$Time[.]-3,       #construct df for that row
                          df$Time[.]+3, 1), 
               Measurement = df$Measurement[.]))

# A tibble: 21 x 2
   Time       Measurement
   <date>           <dbl>
 1 2017-11-25          11
 2 2017-11-26          11
 3 2017-11-27          11
 4 2017-11-28          11
 5 2017-11-29          11
 6 2017-11-30          11
 7 2017-12-01          11
 8 2020-08-21          42
 9 2020-08-22          42
10 2020-08-23          42
# ... with 11 more rows
```